# Cron / wget jobs intermittently not running - not getting into access log

Tags: linux, cron, wget

I've a number of accounts running cron-started php jobs hourly.
The generic structure of the command is this:

```
wget -q -O - http://some.site.com/cron.php
```

Now, this used to be running just fine.

Lately, though, on a number of accounts it has started playing up - but only on this one server.  Once or twice a day the php file is not run.

The access log is missing the relevant entry.
While the cron log shows that the job was run.

We've added a bit to the command to log things out (-o /tmp/logfile) but it shows nothing.
I'm at a loss, really.  I'm looking for ideas what can be wrong, or how to sidestep this issue as it has started taking up way too much of my time.

Has anyone seen anything remotely like this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Try this command

```
wget -d -a /tmp/logfile -O - http://some.site.com/cron.php
```

With `-q` you turn off wget's output. With `-d` you turn on debug output (maybe `-v` for verbose output is already enough). With `-a` you append logging messages to `/tmp/logfile` instead of always creating a new file.

You can also use curl:

```
curl http://some.site.com/cron.php
```

Comment: Thanks, will see to especially the -d & -a.  I don't realy want to redirect the output to /dev/null as I need it to see if the process has run properly - it handles errors gracefully and gives me an indication of problems further down the line.  Unless there's a specific reason you recommend redirect the output?

Comment: ``-O -`` redirects the downloaded file to ``stdout``. If you did not redirect the output of the cron job to a file, this output is lost (same as providing ``-O /dev/null``). This has nothing to with the log messages generating by ``-d``. They are redirected to a file via ``-a``.

Comment: RE the "-O -" : it's not lost; it is sent to the email address of the crontab - me :)